# How to convert a CVImageBufferRef to UIImage

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimage

I am trying to capture video from a camera. i have gotten the `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:` callback to trigger and it gives me a sample buffer that i then convert to a `CVImageBufferRef`. i then attempt to convert that image to a `UIImage` that i can then view in my app.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
    /*Lock the image buffer*/
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0); 
    /*Get information about the image*/
    uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); 
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer); 

    /*We unlock the  image buffer*/
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    /*Create a CGImageRef from the CVImageBufferRef*/
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 
    CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst); 
    CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext); 

    /*We release some components*/
    CGContextRelease(newContext); 
     CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

     /*We display the result on the custom layer*/
    /*self.customLayer.contents = (id) newImage;*/

    /*We display the result on the image view (We need to change the orientation of the image so that the video is displayed correctly)*/
    UIImage *image= [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
    self.capturedView.image = image;

    /*We relase the CGImageRef*/
    CGImageRelease(newImage);
}
```

the code seems to work fine up until the call to `CGBitmapContextCreate`. it always returns a `NULL` pointer. so consequently none of the rest of the function works. no matter what i seem to pass it the function returns null. i have no idea why.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The way that you are passing on the baseAddress presumes that the image data is in the form

ACCC

( where C is some color component, R || G || B ).

If you've set up your AVCaptureSession to capture the video frames in native format, more than likely you're getting the video data back in planar YUV420 format. (see: [link text](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureVideoDataOutput/videoSettings) )  In order to do what you're attempting to do here, probably the easiest thing to do would be specify that you want the video frames captured in kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA .  Apple recommends that you capture the video frames in kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA if you capture it in non-planar format at all, the reasoning for which is not stated, but I can reasonably assume is due to performance considerations.

Caveat:  I've not done this, and am **assuming** that accessing the CVPixelBufferRef contents like this is a reasonable way to build the image.  I can't vouch for this actually working, but I /can/ tell you that the way you are doing things right now reliably will not work due to the pixel format that you are (probably) capturing the video frames as.

Comment: Completely the right answer, so just as a comment: kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA isn't available as a capture format on the iPhone 4 at least in iOS 4.2.1. BGRA is fully implemented.

Answer (score 21):

If you need to convert a `CVImageBufferRef` to `UIImage`, it seems to be much more difficult than it should be unfortunately.

Essentially you need to first convert it to `CIImage`, then `CGImage`, and then finally `UIImage`.  I wish I could tell you why.  :)

```objectivec
-(void) screenshotOfVideoStream:(CVImageBufferRef)imageBuffer
{
    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer];
    CIContext *temporaryContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef videoImage = [temporaryContext
                                 createCGImage:ciImage
                                 fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                 CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer),
                                 CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer))];

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:videoImage];
    [self doSomethingWithOurUIImage:image];
    CGImageRelease(videoImage);
}
```

This particular method worked for me when I was converting H.264 video using the `VTDecompressionSession` callback to get the `CVImageBufferRef` (but it should work for any `CVImageBufferRef`).  I was using iOS 8.1, XCode 6.2.

Comment: You don't need all those steps. You can call [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage ... ]

Comment: I tried doing that but it didn't work for me and I just got a solid white image.  For some reason I needed the CIContext to do this (like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7788510/3841734)).  Perhaps it was just my specific case that I needed it.  I'll be honest I don't fully understand all this image format and context stuff.

Answer (score 5):

You can directly call:

```objectivec
self.yourImageView.image=[[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:[CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer]];
```

Comment: This is working but appears to be a lot slower than Livy Storks approach

Answer (score 2):

Benjamin Loulier wrote a really good post on outputting a CVImageBufferRef under the consideration of speed with multiple approaches.

You can also find a working example on github ;)

How about back in time? ;)
Here you go: http://web.archive.org/web/20140426162537/http://www.benjaminloulier.com/posts/ios4-and-direct-access-to-the-camera

Comment: This blog post appears to be gone.