# Reading video frame-by-frame under iOS

Tags: ios, video, frame, avfoundation, core-video

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the individual frames of a video using iOS API.
I tried using AVAssetImageGenerator but it seems to only provide frame to the nearest second which is a bit too rough for my usage.

From what I understand of the documentation, a pipeline of AVAssetReader, AVAssetReaderOutput and CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer I should be able to do something but I'm stuck with a CVImageBufferRef. With this I'm looking for a way to get a CGImageRef or a UIImage but haven't found it.

Real-time is not needed and the more I can stick to provided API the better.

Thanks a lot!

Edit:
Based on this site: http://www.7twenty7.com/blog/2010/11/video-processing-with-av-foundation and this question: [how to convert a CVImageBufferRef to UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152259/how-to-convert-a-cvimagebufferref-to-uiimage) I'm nearing on a solution. Problem, the AVAssetReader stops reading after the first `copyNextSampleBuffer` without giving me anything (the sampleBuffer is NULL).

The video is readable by MPMoviePlayerController. I don't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two links above actually answer my question and the empty `copyNextBufferSample` is an issue with iOS SDK 5.0b3, it works on the device.

Comment: How did you retrieve all frames? I tried the steps mentioned in 7twenty7. In the method **readNextMovieFrame**, I added the `If` condition inside a `While` Loop which breaks only when `movieReader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusCompleted`. I then retrieve the Image as mentioned in the [POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152259/how-to-convert-a-cvimagebufferref-to-uiimage) and added to an array.. But strangely the app crashes even for a video of 6 secs. I know I am doing something foolishly wrong. Can you please help me with this..

Comment: You definitively shouldn't keep frames in an array or you'll blow the memory very quickly (which is probably what happens to you). A 720p frame is about 3.5M uncompressed. At 30fps, make the count :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Any suggestions as to what I should be doing?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Once the video is taken, I want to get the individual frames of the video. The whole set of frames.

Comment: To do what? Because you'll never be able to hold all the frames of a video (longer than a few sec) in memory. You will need to do something with them and drop them as soon as possible. For reference I needed this for this project: https://github.com/epicagency/cinegraphr and in every parts of the app I have to work with intermediate movie clips to avoid keeping too much in memory.

Comment: How would you handle the app going into the background while you are processing a frame?  How do you resume where you left off once the app returns to active or foreground state?

Answer (score 1):

`AVAssetImageGenerator` has very loose default tolerances for the exact frame time that is grabbed.  It has two properties that determine the tolerance: `requestedTimeToleranceBefore` and `requestedTimeToleranceAfter`.  These tolerances default to `kCMTimePositiveInfinity`, so if you want exact times, set them to `kCMTimeZero` to get exact frames.

(It may take longer to grab the exact frames than approximate frames, but you state that realtime is not an issue.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [AVReaderWriter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ReaderWriter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011124). Though its an OS X Apple sample code, AVFoundation is available on both platforms with little changes.