# Capturing a portion of frames from Video using Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to develop an application like Talking Tom. I am playing a video in the UIView with MPMoviePlayerController. I got a source code for capturing UIView screen. It should work if I do not added MPMoviePlayerController. It will give a video. But if I added a MPMoviePlayerController and capture the same View, only a black screen is showing in the video. Can anyone suggest an easy way to implement this feature.

Main objective is to capture the view in which video is playing, when record button is pressed and when stop button is pressed, I need to get a video from the point where record button pressed to stop button pressed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this one 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714273/how-to-record-video-of-screen-like-talking-tom-cat-on-iphone/5013974#5013974

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:?

[Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2)

Comment: Yes I tried to get frame images at each second. But I need all the frame images in each second. For example, if the video is 24fps, each second contains 24 frame images and I need to get all the frame images. How it can be possible?

Comment: Hm, I haven't had to do that yet.  But I think this may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783214/reading-video-frame-by-frame-under-ios