# How to Convert UIImage to CIImage and vice versa

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, uiimage, core-graphics, core-image

I'm trying to get `CIImage` from ImageView that display on the screen.

```
UIImage *image = myImageView.image;
```

convert image `UIImage` to `CIImage`.

```
CIImage *cImage = [....];
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

```
CIImage *ciImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"].CIImage;
UIImage *uiImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:ciImage];
```

To fix the case where `myUIImage.CIImage` returns `nil` like `[UIImageView image]`, you can instead do `[CIImage imageWithCGImage:myUIImage.CGImage]` – Dylan Hand

**Swift version:**

```
let ciImage = UIImage(named: "test.png")!.ciImage
let uiImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)
```

To fix the case where `myUIImage.ciImage` returns `nil` like you can instead do `CIImage(cgImage: myUIImage!.cgImage!)`.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is always going be a call to alloc... `[UIImage imageWithCIImage:ciImage]` is equivalent to `[[[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:ciImage] autorelease]`

Comment: Just be careful.  If the `UIImage` was initialized with a `CGImageRef` `CIImage` will be `nil` and this won't work.

Comment: The `UIImage` created with `...WithCIImage:` does have some problems with resizing, because most frameworks with `UIImage` need a `CGImage`. So you need to render it first with `createCGImage:fromRect:` or something like it.

Comment: To fix the case where `myUIImage.CIImage` returns `nil`, you can instead do `[CIImage imageWithCGImage:myUIImage.CGImage]`.

Comment: If possible,  it would be better to use  imageWithCIImage:scale:orientation instead of imageWithCIImage        
        CIImage* aCIImage = [CIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        
        UIImage* anImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:aCIImage scale:1.0 orientation:orientation];

Answer (score 33):

While Changxing Wang's answer is effectively correct, Apple says that UIImage.CIImage won't always work.  Specifically, from PocketCoreImage:

```
// Create a CIImage from the _inputImage.  While UIImage has a property returning
// a CIImage representation of it, there are cases where it will not work.  This is the
// most compatible route.
_filteredImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:_inputImage.CGImage options:nil];
```

Apple also uses the following, which DOESN'T work for me:

```
[UIImage imageWithCIImage:_filteredImage]
```

My personal implementation, adapted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788438/having-trouble-creating-uiimage-from-ciimage-in-ios5) does work for me:

```
// result is a CIImage, output of my filtering.  
// returnImage is (obviously) a UIImage that I'm going to return.
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
UIImage *returnImage = 
[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:result fromRect:result.extent]];
```

Comment: Be careful about setting up contexts unless you absolutely have to as it's a generally expensive task. I'd suggest setting up as @property and creating it before you deal with the image conversion. 

If you're only doing this once, though, the above solution should work fine.

Comment: Created CGImageRef will be retained. You must keep reference to it and after creating UIImage call CGImageRelease(cgimage). Otherwise the memory will be leaked

Comment: Your code leaks: [context createCGImage...] creates a CGContextRef that must be released (even in ARC). Since you don't assign it to a variable, you cannot release it, and you leak quite a bit of memory here.

Answer (score 26):

This is most compatibile way of doing it:

```
UIImage* u =[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
CIImage* ciimage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:u.CGImage];
```

now use ciimage...

and Swift version:

```
let i1 = UIImage(named: "testImage")
if let cgi1 = i1?.cgImage {
   let ci = CIImage(cgImage: cgi1)
   //use ci
}
```

(fixed typo in the if let statement)

Comment: To create a CIImage from a UIImage, using the initWithCGImage was the only solution that worked. Doing 'uiimagei.CIImage did not work, it was nil always.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a complete code sample that I've used in my projects.

```
- (UIImage *)makeUIImageFromCIImage:(CIImage *)ciImage {
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:[ciImage extent]];

    UIImage* uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);

    return uiImage;
}
```

`CIImage` is basically a recipe for an image. You will run into problems if you try to directly convert from `CIImage` to `UIImage`. For example, calling

```
NSData * UIImageJPEGRepresentation (
   UIImage *image,
   CGFloat compressionQuality
);
```

will return `nil`.

Answer (score 12):

```
func toCIImage(image: UIImage) -> CIImage {
    return image.CIImage ?? CIImage(CGImage: image.CGImage!)
}

func toUIImage(image: CIImage) -> UIImage {
    return UIImage(CIImage: image)
}
```

Comment: it doesn't convert anything, would return `nil` if wasn't constructed from ciimage

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3/4

**UIImage > CIImage**

`let ciimage = CIImage(image: image)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624090-init

**CIImage > UIImage**

`let image = UIImage(ciImage: ciimage)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/1624119-init

Answer (score 5):

Swift example of [changx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080860/changx)'s answer:

```
guard let ciimage = CIImage(image: uiimage) else { return }
let image = UIImage(CIImage: ciimage)
```

Comment: it doesn't convert anything, would return `nil` if wasn't constructed from ciimage

Comment: Don't you need a context?

Answer (score 1):

When converting UIImage to CIImage, I had 2 separate cases where it's sometimes nil and sometimes not. Below code solved it:

```
CIImage *ciImage;
ciImage=[[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:imageToConvert];
if (ciImage==nil)
    ciImage=imageToConvert.CIImage;
```