# Output Image gives NULL after applying CIFilter

Tags: iphone, ios, ciimage

I want to give effects on the image with `CIImage framework`, and when i set parameters for that the out put image shows blank image.

Any suggestions?

Code is used to apply filter is as  follows :

```
- (IBAction)filterImage:(id)sender {

    CIImage *rawImageData;
    rawImageData =[[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:self.imageView.image];

    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIDepthOfField"];
    [filter setDefaults];

    [filter setValue:rawImageData forKey:@"inputImage"];

    [filter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(50, 50)]
              forKey:@"inputPoint1"];

    [filter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)]
              forKey:@"inputPoint2"];

    [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:15.00]
              forKey:@"inputSaturation"];    

    [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:15.00]
              forKey:@"inputUnsharpMaskRadius"];

    [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:15.70]
              forKey:@"inputRadius"];



    CIImage *filteredImageData = [filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];

    UIImage *filteredImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:filteredImageData];
    self.imageView.image = filteredImage;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are available iOS filters, we can use

```
NSArray *filterNamesArray = [CIFilter filterNamesInCategories:[NSArray arrayWithObject:kCICategoryBuiltIn]];

  $1 = 0x071b8560 <__NSArrayI 0x71b8560>(
    CIAdditionCompositing,
    CIAffineClamp,
    CIAffineTile,
    CIAffineTransform,
    CIBarsSwipeTransition,
    CIBlendWithMask,
    CIBloom,
    CIBumpDistortion,
    CIBumpDistortionLinear,
    CICheckerboardGenerator,
    CICircleSplashDistortion,
    CICircularScreen,
    CIColorBlendMode,
    CIColorBurnBlendMode,
    CIColorControls,
    CIColorCube,
    CIColorDodgeBlendMode,
    CIColorInvert,
    CIColorMap,
    CIColorMatrix,
    CIColorMonochrome,
    CIColorPosterize,
    CIConstantColorGenerator,
    CICopyMachineTransition,
    CICrop,
    CIDarkenBlendMode,
    CIDifferenceBlendMode,
    CIDisintegrateWithMaskTransition,
    CIDissolveTransition,
    CIDotScreen,
    CIEightfoldReflectedTile,
    CIExclusionBlendMode,
    CIExposureAdjust,
    CIFalseColor,
    CIFlashTransition,
    CIFourfoldReflectedTile,
    CIFourfoldRotatedTile,
    CIFourfoldTranslatedTile,
    CIGammaAdjust,
    CIGaussianBlur,
    CIGaussianGradient,
    CIGlideReflectedTile,
    CIGloom,
    CIHardLightBlendMode,
    CIHatchedScreen,
    CIHighlightShadowAdjust,
    CIHoleDistortion,
    CIHueAdjust,
    CIHueBlendMode,
    CILanczosScaleTransform,
    CILightenBlendMode,
    CILightTunnel,
    CILinearGradient,
    CILineScreen,
    CILuminosityBlendMode,
    CIMaskToAlpha,
    CIMaximumComponent,
    CIMaximumCompositing,
    CIMinimumComponent,
    CIMinimumCompositing,
    CIModTransition,
    CIMultiplyBlendMode,
    CIMultiplyCompositing,
    CIOverlayBlendMode,
    CIPinchDistortion,
    CIPixellate,
    CIRadialGradient,
    CIRandomGenerator,
    CISaturationBlendMode,
    CIScreenBlendMode,
    CISepiaTone,
    CISharpenLuminance,
    CISixfoldReflectedTile,
    CISixfoldRotatedTile,
    CISmoothLinearGradient,
    CISoftLightBlendMode,
    CISourceAtopCompositing,
    CISourceInCompositing,
    CISourceOutCompositing,
    CISourceOverCompositing,
    CIStarShineGenerator,
    CIStraightenFilter,
    CIStripesGenerator,
    CISwipeTransition,
    CITemperatureAndTint,
    CIToneCurve,
    CITriangleKaleidoscope,
    CITwelvefoldReflectedTile,
    CITwirlDistortion,
    CIUnsharpMask,
    CIVibrance,
    CIVignette,
    CIVortexDistortion,
    CIWhitePointAdjust
    )
```

Comment: I have used CIDotScreen from the list that you have give, and it works for me. BTW, CIDepth is not in the list so might be it is available for MAC OS.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://sketchytech.blogspot.in/2012/11/adding-filter-to-image-in-xcode-ciimage.html)

and try using the following code

```
  CIImage *filteredImage = [invertColour outputImage];
  UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:filteredImage];
```

Comment: I have tried this solution, but still image shows blank image.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing, which Xcode should warn you about anyway, is that you are using initWithImage: when you should be using initWithCIImage: (I'm guessing that's a typo). Second you should be converting the UIImage returned by self.imageView.image into a CIImage - see [How to Convert UIImage to CIImage and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425647/how-to-convert-uiimage-to-ciimage-and-vise-verse)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
[filter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)]
          forKey:@"inputPoint2"];
```

There is no attribute (key) @"inputPoint2" in CIDepthOfField.

Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIDepthOfField is wrong.

Use @"inputPoint0" and @"inputPoint1" and it will work.

To inspect CIFiter attributes use:

```
[sampleFilterObject attributes]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because **CIDepthOfField**

> Available in OS X v10.6 and later.

(c) Apple documentation

Filter **CIDepthOfField** is **NULL** in iOS device

Comment: Can you add a link to this documentation?

Comment: @jszumski https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIDepthOfField