# Is it possible to detect a rectangle image from a bigger image in IOS swift?

Tags: ios

Say for example I have a business card placed on a desk and I want to scan only the business card out. Something like a QR code scanner, I want to scan a business card image into app.

I have heard of OpenCV but am unsure of how to use it with swift 3. Any suggestions which can guide me in the right direction?

Comment: how you have achieved this? I also want to implement like this

Comment: Solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re looking for object detection, such as a business card, check out the built in “Vision” framework in iOS11. I can’t remember if their WWDC session showed this usage, but I’ll point you towards this [github link](https://github.com/josephchang10/ImageClassificationwithVisionandCoreML/blob/master/Vision%2BML%20Example/ViewController.swift) which uses rectangle detection (like a business card) mixed in with CoreML (which is likely no use to you). I warn you that this isnt my code so I can’t say how bug-free it is, but it will hopefully point you in the right direction. Failing that, the [Apple Documention](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision) is always a good place to start.

Answer (score 5):

Yes ! Using `CIDetector` of `CoreImage` you can detect rectangle . Here is the code ( **Swift 3** ) most probably you are looking for !

```
func performRectangleDetection(image: CIImage) -> CIImage? {
        var resultImage: CIImage?
        resultImage = image
        let detector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeRectangle, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh, CIDetectorAspectRatio: 1.6, CIDetectorMaxFeatureCount: 10] )!

        // Get the detections
        var halfPerimiterValue = 0.0 as Float;
        let features = detector.features(in: image)
        print("feature \(features.count)")
        for feature in features as! [CIRectangleFeature] {

            let p1 = feature.topLeft
            let p2 = feature.topRight
            let width = hypotf(Float(p1.x - p2.x), Float(p1.y - p2.y));
            //NSLog(@"xaxis    %@", @(p1.x));
            //NSLog(@"yaxis    %@", @(p1.y));
            let p3 = feature.topLeft
            let p4 = feature.bottomLeft
            let height = hypotf(Float(p3.x - p4.x), Float(p3.y - p4.y));
            let currentHalfPerimiterValue = height+width;
            if (halfPerimiterValue < currentHalfPerimiterValue)
            {
                halfPerimiterValue = currentHalfPerimiterValue
                resultImage = cropBusinessCardForPoints(image: image, topLeft: feature.topLeft, topRight: feature.topRight,
                                                        bottomLeft: feature.bottomLeft, bottomRight: feature.bottomRight)
                print("perimmeter   \(halfPerimiterValue)")
            }

        }

        return resultImage
    }

    func cropBusinessCardForPoints(image: CIImage, topLeft: CGPoint, topRight: CGPoint, bottomLeft: CGPoint, bottomRight: CGPoint) -> CIImage {

        var businessCard: CIImage
        businessCard = image.applyingFilter(
            "CIPerspectiveTransformWithExtent",
            withInputParameters: [
                "inputExtent": CIVector(cgRect: image.extent),
                "inputTopLeft": CIVector(cgPoint: topLeft),
                "inputTopRight": CIVector(cgPoint: topRight),
                "inputBottomLeft": CIVector(cgPoint: bottomLeft),
                "inputBottomRight": CIVector(cgPoint: bottomRight)])
        businessCard = image.cropping(to: businessCard.extent)

        return businessCard
    }
```

Call the function `performRectangleDetection` , here `cropBusinessCardForPoints` is assistant .

[UIImage/CIImage Conversion .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425647/how-to-convert-uiimage-to-ciimage-and-vice-versa)

Best of Luck !

**FYI** : Using `CoreML` is one of the best option.

Comment: is it possible to identify number of rectangles in an image?

Comment: @Priyal yes it is possible , if you justify over every `feature` in `CIRectangleFeature` s you can get multiple rectangles .