# Why properties method of CIImage returns nil

Tags: ios, iphone, core-image, ciimage

I'm developing an application using coreImage framework.I created a CIImage from UIImage.

```
CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.canvasImage.CGImage];
```

here self.canvasImage is a UIImage,I debug it and object image is being created by compiler with some memory.

i'm creating a NSDictionary object  returned by properties method using following code.

```
NSDictionary *opts  =[image properties] ;
```

here my opts object is being assign with **nil value**.

i searched it but didn't found the solution,**why properties method is returning nil value?**

Comment: Are you using CIContext? ..like here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7788510/1702413

Comment: I suggest using a NSMutableDictionary

Answer (score 5):

I was having this same problem. Turns out the properties dictionary is only non nil if you use the imageWithData: or imageWithContentsOfURL: to create the CIImage.

It's not documented well at all. Check out WWDC 2013 session 509.