# captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection without JPG intermediary

Tags: ios, uiimage, image-capture

I'm trying to get as good an image as possible from the camera, but can only find examples that `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` and then go straight to:

```
NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];    
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

JPEG being lossy and all, is there any way to get the data as PNG, or even just RGBA (BGRA, what-have-you?). AVCaptureStillImageOutput doesn't seem to have any other NSData* methods....

Actually looking at the CMSampleBufferRef, it seems like it's already locked as JPEG ~

```
formatDescription = <CMVideoFormatDescription 0xfe5e1f0 [0x3e5ac650]> {
mediaType:'vide' 
mediaSubType:'jpeg' 
mediaSpecific: {
    codecType: 'jpeg'       dimensions: 2592 x 1936 
} 
extensions: {(null)}
}
```

Is there some other way to take a full-res picture and get the raw data?

Comment: So how did you end up getting the data for PNG? Did you just use kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA instead of kCMVideoCodecType_JPEG?

Comment: Yes ~ https://github.com/blindsightcorp/rawphoto-ios/blob/master/RawPhoto/CaptureSessionManager.m

Comment: thanks, but line 167 shows you using jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation still? how do you convert to PNG?

Comment: My bad on the messy code — that's in a false ifdef. Line 104 is the key. (and 170-183).

Comment: no problem, but where do you convert to PNG output? not clear ...

Comment: The above makes it a non-lossy UIImage. It's actually saved in line 135 of https://github.com/blindsightcorp/rawphoto-ios/blob/master/RawPhoto/MainViewController.m -- if you were up to updating the accepted answer to add this detail, that would be awesome :)

Comment: ok will synthesize your comments for other readers, though will post as a separate answer first since to avoid modifying someone else's code without consent. if slugchewer wants, he will be free of course to incorporate the new answer.

Comment: Why did you set the scale to 1.0? Shouldn't the code use something like UIScreen.mainScreen().scale instead?

Comment: this line `let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)`
 is returning nil and breaking the rest of the code even though the buffer provided in the callback is not nil. did this ever happen to you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to set the outputSettings with a different pixel format.  If you want 32-bit BGRA, for example, you can set:

```
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];
```

From https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureStillImageOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html, the "recommended" pixel formats are:

- `kCMVideoCodecType_JPEG`
- `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange`
- `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA`

Of course, if you're not using JPEG output, you can't use `jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:`, but there's an example here:
[how to convert a CVImageBufferRef to UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152259/how-to-convert-a-cvimagebufferref-to-uiimage)

Comment: Wow. I so should have just tried that, despite `availableImageDataCodecTypes` saying only jpeg was available. I suppose the others aren't codecs, so that makes sense. Much happier. Thanks! :)

Comment: So if you want PNG instead of JPEG output, you use kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA and then use one of the answers to convert from a CVImageBufferRef to UIImage? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Output settings of your connection:

outputSettings
The compression settings for the output.

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *outputSettings
```

You can retreive an NSDictionary of the supported values with

availableImageDataCodecTypes
The supported image codec formats that can be specified in outputSettings. (read-only)

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *availableImageDataCodecTypes
```

Comment: A newly-created AVCaptureStillImageOutput gives an array with one item for availableImageDataCodecTypes: (jpeg). Does that mean I'm just completely SOL for "full res"?