# Capture PNG image instead of JPEG image from AVCaptureStillImageOutput?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, avfoundation

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571242/capturestillimageasynchronouslyfromconnection-without-jpg-intermediary) addresses the same topic, but the selected answer doesn't state how to capture a PNG image instead of a JPEG image when using `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`.

How can you produce a PNG image instead of a JPEG image when capturing still images with `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`?