# Capture video using ios front camera and convert into sequence of image using avassetimagegenerator

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Iam trying to capture video using front camera in ios and convert that into  sequence of images I am trying to use avassetimagegenerator  for that . Iam new to AV Foundation please help me in this , thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First present an UIImagePickerController

```
- (void)presentVideoPicker {
    UIImagePickerController *anImagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    anImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    anImagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    anImagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    anImagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    anImagePicker.delegate = self;

    UIPopoverController *aPopoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:anImagePicker] autorelease];
    [aPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.frame inView:[[self view] window]
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Capture the Video in UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSString *aMediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([aMediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {
        NSURL *aVideoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        [self readMovie:aVideoURL];

        // If you want the Duration fo the Video, Use this
        AVPlayerItem *aPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:aVideoURL];
        CMTime aDuration = aPlayerItem.duration;
        float anInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(aDuration);
        NSInteger aDuration = nearbyintf(anInSeconds);
    }
}
```

Now code for the Method you called in the Delegate `- (void) readMovie:(NSURL *)url`

> Refer this link:
>   http://www.7twenty7.com/blog/2010/11/video-processing-with-av-foundation

...

Once you generate the CVImageBuffer for an Image,

> Refer
>   [how to convert a CVImageBufferRef to UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152259/how-to-convert-a-cvimagebufferref-to-uiimage)

to convert it to UIImage

Comment: how to create CVImageBuffer ?

Comment: in method `- (void) readNextMovieFrame`, you get the CVImageBufferRef for each frame right...