# Error code -8969, -12909 while decoding h264 in iOS 8 with video tool box

Tags: ios, video-streaming, decode, h.264

I have the h264 stream inAnnex B format and follow this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26012146/decoding-h264-in-ios-8-with-video-tool-box") to implements h264 decoding with iOS8 videoToolBox.

I check the OSStatus in every step.

1. use CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets with the SPS and PPS data to create a CMFormatDescription.(status == noErr)
2. create a VTDecompressionSession using VTDecompressionSessionCreate. (status == noErr)
3. capture the NALUnit payload into a CMBlockBuffer making sure to replace the start code with
   a byte length code. (status == noErr)
4. create a CMSampleBuffer. (status == noErr)
5. use VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame and get error code -8969(simulator), -12909(device) in 
   callback function.

I doubt I did something wrong in step3, I am not pretty sure what the length code means. I just follow the WWDC session video replace every NALUnit start code 00 00 00 01 to 00 00 80 00. Is it right or not ? or I should check something else ?? thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally, got it working now. 
So, I share the details on how to use the VideoToolbox to decode h.264 stream data:

1. Get SPS & PPS NALUs from H.264 stream data (or SDP)
2. Create `CMFormatDescription` by using `CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets`.
3. Create `VTDecompressionSession` by using `VTDecompressionSessionCreate`.
4. Get NALUnit payload into a `CMBlockBuffer`.
5. Replace the start code with a 4 byte length code. (ps: length = NALUnit length - start code length)
6. Create a `CMSampleBuffer` by using `CMSampleBufferCreate`.
7. Use `VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame` and get the result from callback.

then, you have to use dispatch_semaphore_t to control frame decoding and showing.
I upload the [sample project on my git](https://github.com/htaiwan/HWDecoder). hope to help someone else.

Comment: Thanks! Looking at your code made me realize that I was not byte-swapping the NALU length code. It has to be in big-endian format.

Comment: The link is broken.  Do you happen to have the VideoToolboxDemo uploaded somewhere else.  This is exactly what I am trying to do and I am struggling.

Comment: Can someone provide some code for the step 4 and 5 above? I'm stucked on it and can't find a solution...

Comment: Try something like this, sorry for bad formatting.

int offset = _spsSize + _ppsSize;
long blockLength = totalFrameSize - offset;
uint8_t* data = malloc(blockLength);
data = memcpy(data, &frame.data[offset], blockLength);
            
uint32_t dataLength32 = htonl (blockLength - 4);
memcpy (data, &dataLength32, sizeof (uint32_t));
            
OSStatus status = CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock(NULL, data, blockLength, kCFAllocatorNull, NULL, 0, blockLength, 0, &blockBuffer);
            
NSLog(@"BlockBufferCreation: \t %@", (status == kCMBlockBufferNoErr) ? @"successful!" : @"failed...");

Comment: @LivyStork what type of object is "frame"? It seems more code is needed to interpret your comment and more information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @3rdLion Well you only asked about steps 4 and 5 :) The data frame should be an entire NALU that you received from a raw H.264 stream. Whether or not it's a P or I frame depends on if there are SPS and PPS parameters involved. Sorry for not going into more specifics, I can only give so much info in a stack overflow comment. I'll reply tomorrow and try to help out more.

Comment: @LivyStork a complete example would be super helpful. The issue is that this new iOS8 decoding isn't documented at a level for practical application. Getting rather desperate in my efforts to make it work. Maybe throw something up on Github? or contact me directly :p

Comment: @3rdLion I agree there aren't many complete examples online.  It took me a few weeks to learn everything ground up, so maybe I can help by posting an example on stackoverflow.  I'll try to get that done today and will comment here again when I'm done.

Comment: @3rdLion I have posted a pretty long example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525000/how-to-use-videotoolbox-to-decompress-h-264-video-stream/).  Feel free to ask questions there.  I didn't cover how to fetch the raw H.264 video data since that varies wildly depending on the situation, but I covered all the other steps.